# titlecase pipe does not work with ternary operator angular2

Tags: angular, ternary-operator, ngfor, title-case

I have this code in component.html

```
<div class="dashboard-table-item row"
       *ngFor="let item of itemArray">
  <span>{{item.value == 'user' ? 'student' : item.value  | titlecase}}</span>
</div>
```

**itemArray** can have one of this values: admin | editor | user
I want without modifying the **itemArray** output: user --> student and then titlecase it.

I know I could change 'student' for 'Student' and it works, but my question is why does pipe(| titlecase) not work with ternary operator(condition ? 'value1' : item.value) **Value1**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try wrapping your ternary condition with parenthesis `()`. This worked for me:

```
<div class="dashboard-table-item row"
   *ngFor="let item of itemArray">
  <span>{{(item.value == 'user' ? 'student' : item.value ) | titlecase}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, all I needed!

Comment: This will also work for a situation like this:  `<span> {{ object.property ? (object.property | <pipe>) : "None" }} </span`